# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, xcode6

[image][image]i have sqlite3.dylib also in my application, but it give me that upper error i don't know that how to fix this error. please someone help me i am waiting?

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

"_sqlite3_open", referenced from:

-[MyDataBase openOrCreateDatabase:] in MyDataBase.o
[image]
"_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:

-[MyDataBase createTable:] in MyDataBase.o

-[MyDataBase InsertTable:] in MyDataBase.o

-[MyDataBase UpdataTable:] in MyDataBase.o

-[MyDataBase queryTableByCallBack:] in MyDataBase.o

"_sqlite3_close", referenced from:

-[MyDataBase closeDatabase] in MyDataBase.o

"_sqlite3_get_table", referenced from:

-[MyDataBase queryTable:] in MyDataBase.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Maybe you forgot  `#import <sqlite3.h>` ?

Comment: #import <sqlite3.h>  is import in my project #Dave

Comment: Well if you've linked binaries already, try cleaning out your build folder and re-building.

Comment: #Dave i updared my question ..... i clean my project but it give me this errors as in image

Comment: When you cleaned did you hold down the option key?

Comment: @Dave, you're probably confusing linker errors with compiler errors. `#include`/`#import` directives have no effect on linker errors.

Comment: @zneak Your right I was confusing them.

Comment: SoftCoder, you can copy and paste from the build window instead of taking a screenshot. This is much easier to look through. Make sure that you link against libsqlite3. In your project, pick "Build Phases", unfold "Link Binary With Libraries", and click the plus if you need to add it.

Comment: @zneak now check i updated my question

Comment: So what are your architecture build settings?

Comment: @matt i updated my question see that one

Comment: Looks good but I would try removing sqlite.dylib from the linked libraries and adding it again.

Comment: @matt i remove and add again but it give me the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're showing us the linked libraries for the "Fortress of Muslim" target, but your linker error is happening on the other target, the "Fortress of MuslimTests" target.

Either remove the dependency to SQLite in the "Tests" target, or include SQLite to the list of linked libraries for that target.

Comment: @SoftCoder You removed what from "Test"? Your error is telling you that the Tests target includes `DBHandler` and it uses `sqlite3_open`. You need to either _add_ SQLite library to "Test" target, or you need to remove the code that is trying to link to `sqlite3_open` from the Test compile sources.